# How do I group by for every rolling 3 rows in google cloud sql or python dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, group-by, google-cloud-sql

Let's say I have a dataset.

```
Year | Month | Count
2017 | 1     | 3
2017 | 2     | 4
2017 | 3     | 2
2017 | 4     | 1
2017 | 5     | 5
2017 | 6     | 6
```

I want the group by result to be

```
group 1    | total count
month1,2,3 |    9
month2,3,4 |    7
month3,4,5 |    8
...
```

I wonder is there a way to do this in google cloud SQL? if not, can I do this in python dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `sum()`.  Assuming `month` is a string:

```
select concat(month, ',', lead(month) over (order by year, month), ',',
              lead(month, 2) over (order by year, month)
             ),
       sum(count) over (order by year, month rows between current row and 2 following) as total
from t;
```

Or:

```
with t as (
      select 2017 as year, 1 as month, 3 as count union all
      select 2017, 2, 4 union all
      select 2017, 3, 2 union all
      select 2017, 4, 1 union all
      select 2017, 5, 5 union all
      select 2017, 6, 6
     )
select array_to_string(array_agg(cast(count as string)) over (order by year, month rows between current row and 2 following), ','),
       sum(count) over (order by year, month rows between current row and 2 following)
from t;
```

Using `array_agg()` as a window function is probably a bit more cumbersome than `lead()`.  However, for a few more elements, it would be simpler.